# is it possible to get the generated key from an insert using a handle in JDBI?

Tags: database, jdbi

I know there is @GeneratedKeys, but I can't use it with a handler (I am using a handler in my tests).

Comment: Can you please add more code examples (for example the handler in your test?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely it is possible to retrieve generated keys (e.g., auto-increment primary keys) using a handle (I'm assuming you mean *handle* rather than *handler*). For example, assuming an integer generated key:

```
handle.createStatement("INSERT ...")
    .bind("foo", foo)
    .executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys(IntegerMapper.FIRST).first();
```

Note that there is a dependency on the JDBC driver supporting `java.sql.Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`, but if the annotation-driven return approach works for your database I'd expect this approach will as well.

Answer (score 9):

In JDBI 3, this has changed to

```
 handle.createUpdate("INSERT ...")
   .bind("foo", foo)
   .executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys("id")
   .mapTo(Long.class)
   .one()
```